# Как отсортировать map<Long,Object> по объекту object

Tags: java, java-8

Подскажите как сортируется `map` с выводом на экран, состоящая из `Long` и `Pet`? Перед выводом на экран необходима сортировка по трём полям одновременно внутри `Pet: person name -> pet name -> pet weight`.
Сам класс `Pet` состоит из полей характеристик и объекта `Person`:

```
Pet(String name, double weight, Type type, Person persons);

public void displayPet() {

    for (Map.Entry<Long, Pet> item : mapPet.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("ID: " + item.getKey() + ", name: " + item.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, так(только перменную weight сделайте ссылочной либо перепишите последнюю строку в фильтре):

```
Map<Long, Pet> result = mapPet.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
            int personName = e1.getValue().getPerson().getName().compareTo(e2.getValue().getPerson().getName());                    
            if (personName!=0) return personName;
            int petName = e1.getValue().getName().compareTo(e2.getValue().getName()); 
            if (petName!=0) return petName;
            return e1.getValue().getWeight().compareTo(e2.getValue().getWeight()); 
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (o1,o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Если предположить, что сортировка Pet может ещё где-то понадобиться, лучше сделать `Pet implements Comparable<Pet>` и код сравнения поместить в `compareTo`.

Comment: @Дмитрий Никифоров ну в таком случае давайте предполагать не только это. а, например, что сортировка потребуется в другом месте и по другим критериям. тогда лучше компаратор отдельно написать)) таких предположений можно сделать много, тут надо уточнять у автора, что именно ему надо

Comment: Так вы и написали компаратор, просто анонимный в виде лямбды) Мой комментарий не претензия, а дополнение к ответу, чтобы люди не копипастили код сравнения бездумно.

Comment: @Дмитрий Никифоров да, я понимаю, просто вопрос так сформулирован. в вопросе есть конкретный метод, класс Pet вообще не приведен. поэтому и решение такое - реализуем метод))

Comment: класс Pet это класс с параметрами и конструктором, который прикрепил в вопросе

Comment: @DMITRIY BLAZHKO под параметрами класса вы, видимо, понимаете его поля. конструктор в классе есть всегда(даже если вы его не пишите). суть обсуждения совершенно не в этом. для решения задачи достаточно понимать, какие поля нужны для сортировки. весь вопрос в том, где будет реализован компаратор.

Comment: @ДмитрийНикифоров спасибо за помощь! несколько часов вчера боролся с этой проблемой не мог понять суть

Comment: @DMITRIY BLAZHKO да не за что))

Comment: @ДмитрийНикифоров переписал часть кода под свой класс 
                    if (personName != 0) return personName;
                    int petName = e1.getValue().getName().compareTo(e2.getValue().getName());
                    if (petName != 0) return petName;
                    return Double.compare(e1.getValue().getWeight(), e2.getValue().getWeight());
                })

Comment: @Дмитрий я пытался реализовать отдельно компаратор под каждое поле и делать что то в виде^ Compararot.comparing(new PersonNameComparator).thenComparing(new PetNameComparator).thenComparint(PetWeightComparator)  но не получилось его запихнуть в Map

Comment: @DMITRIY BLAZHKO компаратор под каждое поле - плохая идея. класс - компаратор лучше писать под каждый кейс сортировки. например, в данном случае вы хотите сортировать по 3 полям. тогда один компаратор должн обеспечит такую сортировку.  далее вам потребуется сортировка по 2 другим полям - еще один компаратор.